# How to go fullscreen with multiple instances of an application started in a shell script on OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, fullscreen

This script somewhat works, it sets one or a couple of instances fullscreen once they are clicked on. Looking for a way to go fullscreen with each one after another.

```
set REAKTOR to "Reaktor 6"


tell application "System Events"
    
    repeat with reaktorInstance in (every process whose name contains REAKTOR)
        
        tell application "System Events"
            tell reaktorInstance
                activate
                set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of every window to true
            end tell
        end tell
        
    end repeat
end tell
```

Anyone has any idea on how to get this working reliably every time?

Comment: Where is it failing? Have you ensured the system can actually tell each instance from the others? Are you certain they are in fact separate instances - as the Mac is far more likely to consider them as documents within one instance.

Comment: @Tetsujin. Yes, resizing and positioning works, and instances are clearly addressed.
They are application instances, and they show up in the dock, have pids, etc.
They don't go full screen unless they are clicked to be in foreground.

Comment: & 'activate' is not bringing each forwards?

Comment: No. It makes a click sound, like on an invalid keypress, ...

Comment: Have you tried running it from within Script Editor & seeing what the Results says? [Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't, depending on how the script is capable of reading its own return values]

Comment: Yes, of course. It never gives any output.

Comment: It's no good saying 'of course'. We can't know what you did or didn't do unless you tell us.

Comment: I'm running this script from both the editor, and with shell invocation, the script behaves the same.